# Send Log4J INFO to database and DEBUG to Console?

Tags: java, log4j

I have *com.mycompany.library.**

I want DEBUG go to console, and INFO go to DB. how I can achieve it?
this is part of my log4j.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false"
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <!-- APPENDERS LIST -->
    <!-- show log entries on console -->

    <appender name="ConsoleApp" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-16.16t][%32.32c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DBAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
        <param name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB" />
        <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <param name="user" value="postgres" />
        <param name="password" value="password" />
        <param name="sql"
            value="INSERT INTO logs(user_id, dated,logger,lev,message) VALUES('%t', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%-50c{3}','%p','%m')" />
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mycompany">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="DBAppender" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.mycompany.library">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleApp" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="DBAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

With this config:
INFO and DEBUG goes to console. But Also INFO and DUBUG with double entries go to DB.

I want that to DB goes events with INFO level(and higher), not DEBUG. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a treshold on your appenders (not on the loggers). For instance:

```
<appender name="std-out" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">...</layout>
    <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
</appender>
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogByLevel

edit: You also don't have to set an appender on both the `com.mycompany` logger and the root logger. This is why you have duplicate entries, because they are treated as additive (so at the level of `com.mycompany`, you essentially have 2 DB appenders).

Just set DBAppender on root and remove it from the `com.mycompany` logger.

Comment: Yep. I added <param name="Threshold" value="info"/> to DBAppender. And into DB goes only INFO events. But still with this config of loggers and root, into DB goes double entries :(